# Remove a user account from user info list without being a site collection admin

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions, pnp-powershell, user-accounts

I am trying to remove a cached user account added in more than 18000 sites. for that I have been trying below PNP script:

```
$displayName = "DisplayNameOfAccountThatNeedTobeRemoved"
    
Get-PnPTenantSite | ForEach-Object {
   $site = $_
   Write-Host "Processing $($site.Url)..."
   Connect-PnPOnline $site.Url -Credentials $creds
   Get-PnPUser | ? Title -like $displayName | Remove-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin
}
```

But it is giving me an error "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."

I have also tried **Remove-SPOUSer** cmdlet too but it is giving me same error message.

I cannot add my account as a site collection admin on all the sites due to compliance and efficiency purposes. I do have SharePoint admin rights though.

Answer (score 0):

By default, user information list is only visible and accessible by each site collection administrators.

I don't think it's possible to remove a user account from user information list without being a site collection administrator.